# Ubuntu refusing every connection, after massive permission meltdown in /etc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, remote-connection

This morning, while trying to migrate some files from my test server to my live server; I made a horrible mistake.

I was trying to pull my `/etc/apache2` from the sandbox, and put it live, so I was temporarily changing the permissions in `/etc/apache2` to **777**, while I was migrating.

However, I had a massive distraction and changed the permissions in `/etc` to **777**. Anyhow, I spent the last four hours fixing this problem, and it all more or less works.

I managed to get sudoers back to **0440**, and everything else is at **755**, which is more or less neutral.

But now, Ubuntu is instantly refusing every single kind of remote connection from every computer (except Apache, MySQL, PhpMyAdmin). When I try to make a remote connection from Putty, Tunnelier or WINSCP it just ***instantly*** refuses it with some error message like "**Network Error**".

Anyhow, I really don't want to hear how stupid I am for making this mistake, trust me; I have been hating myself all morning. But if anybody has some suggestions on how I can fix this problem, I almost certain that it is due to permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you are required to at least `chown root` and `chmod go-rwx` the openssh private key; Read access only on the public key;

Same requirements may go for other keys but I'm assuming ssh is your first point of entry for this server. The man page for ssh (sshd_config) will have the exact details

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, gonna go take a look there. :)

Comment: Thanks a ton, you solved it. In fact, it works better than before.